# Possible to stream images (video) from C# using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, stream, html5-canvas

I've created a C# program which captures the screen as a Jpeg image and saves it to a file. Then using HTML5's Canvas, I'm using this code to pull in the image and display it, updating every 8 milliseconds so it looks like a video.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function draw() {
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
                var img=new Image();
                img.src="C://wamp/www/test.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();

                img.onload = function() {
                    cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                };
            }

            function start() {
                setInterval("draw()",15);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="start()">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="720"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Doing this locally gives a good picture (a bit choppy, but still good) but doing it over the internet is useless. Is there a way to stream the image straight from the C# program instead of using a file? Would that update it quick enough for a good picture? Or shall I compress the image in the C# program? Just looking for any pointers of how to make this work. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can manage to code the delivery-method, it shouldn't be any worse than attaching a html5-video element to a endpoint in your app :)

But it might involve transcoding jpeg-images to h264 on the fly ;)

Comment: Thanks Christian! Looking at it though I don't think M-JPEG would work because I want to also capture input from the user. Is it possible to compress jpg images and then decompress for displaying on the canvas?

Comment: Maybe "compressing" is the wrong word to use, as they are already compressed, right? Is there any way to make them smaller in kb?

Comment: Are you trying to make a HTML5-canvas remote desktop?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that but for a game. So the game is running on the PC while a laptop can view and control it. This is what I've done so far: http://tehwebz.com/stream/streamTest.php I can lower the quality of the images so that it runs smoother, but doing that makes it pointless. Could I use a compressing algorithm to make it work better? Or am I going about it all wrong? Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: By lowering the quality, I mean compressing the images more. :)